# How to open an embedded SWF file in mobile browser?

Tags: javascript, html, embed, flash

I am trying to embed a SWF file in HTML by using JavaScript, but mobile browsers  doesn't support it and so the swf file cannot be opened ever.

In mobile browsers it is only showing the below error message:

> **This plugin is not supported**

If browser does not support, it is showing button to download player.

This is my code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    AC_FL_RunContent( 'codebase','http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,18,0','width','100%','height','100%','src','images/map','quality','high','scale','exactfit','pluginspage','http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer','movie','images/map' ); //end AC code
</script>
<embed allowFullScreen="true" src="img/swf/map.swf" alt="Virtual Tours Of Chianti" quality="high" scale="exactfit" allowFullScreen="true" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"> 
<noscript>
    &lt;object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,18,0" width="750" height="380"&gt;
    &lt;param name="movie" value="images/map.swf" /&gt;
    &lt;param name="quality" value="high" /&gt;
    &lt;param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"&gt;
    &lt;embed src="img/swf/map.swf" alt="Virtual Tours Of Chianti" quality="high" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="100%" height="100%" allowFullScreen="true" SCALE="exactfit" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" /&gt;
    &lt;/object&gt;
</noscript>
```

How to fix it?

Comment: I have reworded the title and content to correct grammar errors, improved the formatting of the code block and also highlighted the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Flash is not supported so you will need to have a fall back to mp4 video.